# No exception for duplicates with gmongo

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, groovy, duplicates

I have tried to insert duplicates into a mongodb database with both Groovy and Java. Java raises an exception while the groovy version just quietly ignores to insert the duplicate.

Here is some example code that illustrate this. I am running on OsX, Mongodb version 2.4.4. Can anyone enlighten me on this? Most grateful!

```
package chapter3

import com.gmongo.GMongo
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.DB
import com.mongodb.DBCollection
import com.mongodb.MongoClient

class TweetArchiveWithJava {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        new TweetArchiveWithJava()
    }

    private static final int ASCENDING = 1

    TweetArchiveWithJava() {
        duplicateInsertGroovy()
        duplicateInsertJava()
    }

    def duplicateInsertJava() {
        println "Inserting duplicates with Java"
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient()
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("twitter-archive")
        DBCollection tweets = db.getCollection("tweets")

        tweets.remove(new BasicDBObject())
        tweets.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("last_name", ASCENDING), "unique_index", true)

        BasicDBObject insertedRecord = new BasicDBObject("last_name", "jones")
        BasicDBObject duplicate = new BasicDBObject("last_name", "jones")
        tweets.insert(insertedRecord)
        System.out.println("Inserted first one")
        printAllTweets(tweets)
        tweets.insert(duplicate)
        System.out.println("What?!! Should not be able to insert duplicates.")

        printAllTweets(db)
    }

    private void duplicateInsertGroovy() {
        println "Inserting duplicates with Groovy"
        def mongo = new GMongo("127.0.0.1", 27017)
        def db = mongo.getDB("twitter-archive")
        DBCollection tweets = db.getCollection("tweets")

        tweets.remove([:])
        tweets.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("last_name", ASCENDING), "unique_index", true)

        def jones = [last_name: "jones"]
        tweets.insert(jones)
        println "Inserted first Jones"
        def duplicate = [last_name: "jones"]
        tweets.insert(duplicate)
        println "Succeeded inserting duplicate"

        println "But only one record is found"
        printAllTweets(tweets)
        println "\n"
    }

    def printAllTweets(tweets) {
        def cursor = tweets.find()
        cursor.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You you can use `WriteResult` for error indication:

```
def jones = [last_name: "jones"]
WriteResult rs =  tweets.insert(jones)
println rs.error
//println "Inserted first Jones"
def duplicate = [last_name: "jones"]
rs = tweets.insert(duplicate)
//println "Succeeded inserting duplicate"
println rs.error
```

Prints:

```
null
E11000 duplicate key error index: twitter.tweets.$unique_index  dup key: { : "jones" }
```

The reason for the difference is the `WriteConcern`:

The java method code uses `{w=1}` (acknowledged)

Whereas groovy method code uses `{w=0}` (normal)

Form `DBTCPConnector`

```
        if ( concern.callGetLastError() ){
            return _checkWriteError( db , port , concern );
        }
        else {
            return new WriteResult( db , port , concern );
        }
```

and in `WriteConcern` :

```
 public boolean callGetLastError(){
    if (_w instanceof Integer)
        return (Integer) _w  > 0;
    return _w != null;
 }
```

So the java method calls `_checkWriteError` behind the scenes - where an exception is thrown - and the groovy method just returns the write result.

The reason that you have different write concerns is initialization code:

You initialize `MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient()` in your java method, which internally uses `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED`.

In your groovy method, the GMongo constructor uses `Mongo` deprecated constructor which internally uses `WriteConcern.NORMAL`.

If you change `tweets.insert(duplicate)` to `tweets.insert(duplicate, WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED)`, you'll get an exception for the groovy method too

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!
I wonder why the difference. What is the purpose?

Comment: [Have a look in here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/)
I guess gmongo hasn't caught up with this change (Still calls Mongo, not MongoClient)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but what happens if you change the groovy version to:

```
    def jones = [last_name: "jones"] as BasicDBObject
    tweets.insert(jones)
    println "Inserted first Jones"
    def duplicate = [last_name: "jones"] as BasicDBObject
    tweets.insert(duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use com.gmongo.GMongoClient. It has the same constructors as com.mongodb.MongoClient.